# Netbeans javac throws exception in LayerGeneratingProcessor for @Override. Where's the problem?

Tags: java, exception, annotations, javac

Im using NB7
I don't know which file is causing the problem since i can't find any stracktraces.
I've checked the **.netbeans\7.0\var\log\** directory, but there's no useful information there (afaik)
I added to **build-impl.xml** the compilerarg **-verbose** and got

```
...
[loading java\lang\annotation\RetentionPolicy.class(java\lang\annotation:RetentionPolicy.class)]
Round 1:
    input files: {...}
    annotations: [java.lang.Override, java.lang.SuppressWarnings]
    last round: false
error: Exception thrown while constructing Processor object: org/openide/filesystems/annotations/LayerGeneratingProcessor
D:\..\nbproject\build-impl.xml:603: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\..\nbproject\build-impl.xml:242: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 8 seconds)
```

Turns out the "**LayerGeneratingProcessor**" is an **Abstract** class. Does anyone know how to stop it from being constructed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved

Problem was that the tickbox '*Enable annotation processing*', under '*Project properties, build, compiling '*, was enabled while nothing was configured for this setting.